# Failed to run dynamically created source file in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

Currently, I am working in an automation project where I need to create one source file and testng.xml file dynamically. The TestNG is getting the xml file but not the source file created dynamically. It's showing error message while I am running the system for the first time:

```
 org.testng.TestNGException: 
 Cannot find class in classpath: domain.companyname.customsuite.CustomTestcase
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
 at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
```

But after refreshing the project it's running fine.

How can I run the dynamically created source file using TestNG?

Comment: You say source file - I assume the source file is also compiled to a .class file BEFORE the xml is actually loaded by TestNG?

Comment: Yes, it is dynamically created source file but TestNg cannot find the file in the classpath. The source file is actually created, but it's not found until I refresh the project/containing folder.

Comment: I am assuming you are not running it using any build tool.Your newly created source file need to build and compile . For that if you use any build tool like Ant or maven then you will not require to refresh it.

Comment: Thanks to all. I've got my job done. I'd to compile the dynamically created source file using java api and had to place the compiled class file in the appropriate directory.